# for one member of list or tuple, why typeerror is given?

Tags: python, list, tuples

if `x = [1,2]`
then `print(x[0])` gives `1`
but, when `x = [1]`
or
`x = (1)`
then `print(x[0])` gives **int object is not subscriptable**.

I actually want to know why it gives an error when a member in the tuple of the list is only 1, but not for more than 1 member!

Comment: `x = [1]`  should not give error. Can you check again?

Comment: Yes you are right brother, i didn't notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`(1)` isn't a tuple, it's just the plain integer value `1` with parentheses around it. Just like you can put parentheses around any arbitrary expression (like e.g. `(1 + 2)`).

To get a single-value tuple you *must* use a comma: `(1,)`.

This should be rather well documented.

Comment: Wow, thanks, didnt think of it that way